# Mysql subquery for group and count records by specific field

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have this problem:

I have a `car` table, each `car` record has a `state` field, `state` field value can be:

**1** = **Enable** or **2** = **Disable**

For example, in this case I need to show all cars **grouped** by `color` field
and **counted** by `color`, this is not problem really :)

Here the SQL statement :

```
SELECT 
  `id`, 
  `model_family`, 
  `color`, 
  COUNT(`color`) AS 'quantity',
  `state` 
FROM `auto` 
WHERE `model_family` = 'Sedan'
GROUP BY `color`

+-----+--------------+------------+----------+---+
| id  | model_family | color  | quantity | state |
+-----+--------------+--------+----------+-------+
|  77 | Sedan        | Red    |        2 |     2 |
|  42 | Sedan        | Blue   |        3 |     2 |
|  97 | Sedan        | Green  |        5 |     1 |
+-----+--------------+--------+----------+-------+
```

Results show **two Disabled** records and **one Enabled** record.

Well, the questions is :

How can I can show the cars disabled and enabled but 
For example, if for first **grouped** record if `state` is disabled (`state` = 2)
then `quantity` field will appear as **"0"** (because it not exists cars enabled) 
else `quantity` = **n**

Something like this:

```
+-----+--------------+------------+----------+-------+
| id  | model_family | color      | quantity | state |
+-----+--------------+------------+----------+-------+
|  77 | Sedan        | Red        |        0 |     2 |
|  42 | Sedan        | Blue       |        0 |     2 |
|  97 | Sedan        | Green      |        5 |     1 |
+-----+--------------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Regads !

Comment: can you provide some sample data set with your table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all disabled groups to be replaced with 0, you can just put a single case statement in your select clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT id, model_family, color, (CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 0 END) AS quantity, state
FROM auto
WHERE model_family = 'Sedan'
GROUP BY color
ORDER BY id;
```

It tested fine with your data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1634/4).

**EDIT** Note, since you're grouping by color, you can just use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(color) because they are going to count the same thing.

**EDIT 2** Also important to note that if a color has some enabled vehicles and some disabled vehicles, it still returns 0 because there is at least one disabled. If you want a count of the enabled ones, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT id, model_family, color, SUM(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS quantityEnabled, state
FROM auto
WHERE model_family = 'Sedan'
GROUP BY color
ORDER BY id;
```

This [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e982b0/2) has both examples.

Comment: @joseluisq Just for my curiosity - which one did you use for what you need?

Comment: Looks good. Just a thought though, why do you have so much repeated data?

Comment: This is the correct fiddle works fine with `SUM` instead `COUNT(*)` --> [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82cd1/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
 `id`, 
 `model_family`, 
 `color`, 
 SUM(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as enabled,
 SUM(CASE WHEN state = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as disabled,
 `state` 
FROM `auto` 
WHERE `model_family` = 'Sedan'
GROUP BY `color`
```

You have to use case statements to group the items together.  When it finds that the state is 1 you will need to sum together all of those records which is why I am doing the Then 1 Else 0.

This was a quick example of how to do it.  I haven't tested to make sure it works, but it should.

Comment: This works, but it doesn't do what OP was looking for, you've added an extra column.

Comment: Exactly this works, although I need to customize a little.  
Thanks bro !